# High CPU usage after waking up from sleep

Tags: windows-7, bsod, sleep

About a month ago I reinstalled windows 7 (x64) on my laptop again. A couple weeks later, every so often when I wake my computer from sleep, the CPU starts working at 70%-95%. I tried waiting it out a couple times and the computer blue screens. It happens more frequently now (id say about every third or fourth time I wake it up). I've looked at the task manager and looked at all of the processes for all users (including system processes), but the sum of the cpu usage column (excluding idle) is like 10. Yet it says the total usage is really high and it takes >30 seconds for the mouse pointer to respond to my movements.

I am typically able to solve my own computer problems, but this one has me baffled because I don't even know what the culprit is. What can use the cpu, but not show up in task manager? Could it be related to something like bad graphics drivers or really hidden virus? My solution here is probably to just live with it until I get around to reinstalling the os again. I am hoping someone else can think of a better solution.

**Update:**
I had the process explorer running every time I put my computer to sleep. This morning when I woke my computer, I noticed that it was happening again. It took me about 5 minutes to actually take the screen shot because of how slow the computer was, but I did get one. Hopefully someone can dissect this for me. 
[image]

Comment: What make and model is the laptop? Often, a problem like this will be experienced by others with the same system and may have already been discussed (and hopefully fixed).

Comment: I have a HP Compaq 8510w running Windows 7 (x64)

Comment: Aha! When I Googled [“interrupts high cpu resume standby”](http://www.google.com/search?q=interrupts+high+cpu+resume+standby) yesterday, an HP thread was one of the top results. Throwing in you model helps (though not *as much* as I had hoped). Still… it looks like some HP systems have this issue. I’ve added links in my comment under my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the kernel times (figure 1) in the *Performance Tab*. Is the red line high?

Task Manager is limited. Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to get a better insight into exactly what is spinning the CPU.

From your description, it sounds like one of the drivers is having a problem. Hopefully all that is required to fix it is to update the driver. Another fairly easy solution would be to adjust certain BIOS settings depending on what is causing the problem.

**Figure 1:** Kernel Times

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this next time it happens. Because I don't know how to recreate the problem at will, I'll have to wait until it happens again.

Comment: Set the kernel-times option (Task Manager remembers it). Then just before closing your laptop next time, run Task Manager and Process Explorer and minimize them to the tray (or even just leave them open). Then when you open the laptop, they should be there, displaying the results.

Comment: I updated the question with some more information. If you think I should move this to a new question, let me know.

Comment: Forget Task Manager and System Explorer. Next time you want to stand by, open Process Explorer, right-click on the column-headers, select *Choose Columns* and check the `Process Image->CPU History` box. Then right-click the `procexp.exe` entry in the list and select `Set Priority->Realtime` (this way ProcExp will be able to show real-time information). Wait until the whole system idles (CPU usage drops to ~0%), then go into standby. When you resume, you can see the culprit because that process’ CPU graph will be obvious. (You can also click the CPU graph at the top and hover over the peaks.)

Comment: I will do this next time it happens. Do you know why the 'Interrupts' cpu usage is so high in the image? It is never anywhere that high normally.

Comment: A high CPU for Interrupts would indicate a problem with a driver. That is why I suggest that you may have to update your drivers. The question of course is *which* driver (though you could always update all drivers that have updates available—one at a time of course).

Comment: The 'Base System Device' driver does have a yellow triangle on it in Device Manager. It says that there is no driver installed for it. Could it be that? I can't seem to update it otherwise I would.

Comment: [Probably not](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and/base-system-device-missing-for-8510w/td-p/1138327), but install the [drivers](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-HP-ProBook-Compaq-Slate/Compaq-8510W-win-XP-32bit-drivers/td-p/2306026) anyway. Other [HP users](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/high-cpu-usage-in-windows-7-hardware-interrupts/8ef44fa3-83b6-441f-9c0a-40fdfe6c960b) have had [similar problems](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/HP-mini5102-high-interrupt-CPU-usage-after-sleep-resume/td-p/275743).

Comment: Turns out it was a combination of drivers, including the graphics driver (mostly the graphics driver. I removed and reinstalled them and everything works great. Thanks!

Comment: Great; glad it’s fixed. (You would think that with the premium paid for brand-name, pre-built systems, they would be tested and work correctly.) `:-|`

Comment: I re-imagined it, so it wasn't straight from the factory, but it was still the recommended driver for my model that broke...

Answer (score 2):

The first step in troubleshooting is to get the data. Here's some tools I suggest you:

**1)** MS TechNet Sysinternals *Process Explorer* to find which process takes so much CPU

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

There many setup possibilities with P.E. but I *suggest* you to try this column set:

- Process (mandatory...)
- PID
- CPU
- Priority
- Command line
- Start time
- CPU Time
- Network receives
- Networks sends

**2)** From the same, dowmload and install *Autoruns* (to know what started with Windows) and *Process Monitor* (for future detailed system checkup like tracing boot process...)

**Warning:** use Autoruns with caution. Don't disable or delete anything unless you really know what's you're doing.

**3)** Download and install *System Explorer* for security checkup.

http://systemexplorer.net/

The processes signatures/checksums are compared to the System Explorer database, There's many useful features but one interesting is the possibility to send any file, program, to *VirusTotal*...

**4)** Check the Windows services

You may start the services.msc but the best is to run mmc.exe and add services.msc in a personalized "console". (This keep your display setup for the next time).

You may find useful information about Windows services at the *BlackViper web site*.

*Hint:* some Windows services slow down Personnal Computers when they are not connected. as a workstation, to a Windows Server such as Server, LanmanWorkStation and LanmanServer.

I suggest you to stop these services if they are running and put them in manual or disabled (IF your PC is NOT connected to a Windows Server...)

Another useful tool is *NirSoft's ServiWin* (for services and drivers...)

**5)** Check if there is defective driver for devices with *devmgmt.msc* (or add it in the same "console" created for services with mmc.exe...). Check if there's yellow triangle, if so update the driver... If not: don't fix what ain't broken...

**6)** Update Windows and your applications. I suggest you to double check with the online *Secunia's Online Software Inspector* and set the option *Enable thorough system inspection* (Java must be installed to run these tests)

**7)** Preventive Maintenance

- Check the s.m.a.r.t. data of your Hard Disk (there's many free
  utilities for this: Piriform's defraggler or Speccy, SpeedFan with an
  online s.m.a.r.t. check up, etc.).
- **IF** the s.m.a.r.t. is "good" run CHKDSK to detect and fix HD and
  FileSystem errors
- Clean "TMPs" files with cleanmgr.exe (or a third party software BUT
  avoid Registry "cleanup")
- Uninstall all unused softwares, UNutilities or "bugaboo" programs
  (alpha, beta, etc.)
- Keep program loaded at startup to a minimum: in Autoruns check
  "Logon" tab...
- Defragment the HD volumes
- Check the PC temperatures (SpeedFan, Speccy, Open Hardware Monitor,
  etc) and remove *dust* in your PC if needed...

Last words:Make a System Restore before any modifications (just in case).

Hope this help you to find a solution. Let us know.  :)

Comment: Thanks, I have everything setup for when it happens again. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: Ok. Give us feed-back. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I tried many of these tests and so far none of the tools have found any major problems and the problem still exists.

Comment: I updated the question with some more information. If you think I should move this to a new question, let me know.

Comment: That’s a bit of a generic, scorched-Earth, try-everything approach. A more narrowed approach specific to this issue based on the symptoms would be better.

Comment: The first step in troubleshooting is to get the data. There's no shortway for this. Based of so few symptoms, the best is to use a systematic approach instead of guessing... The "try-everything" may complicate the problem instead of solving it.  The user talk about BSOD but give us no Bug Check error code , kind of "Stop 0x0 blah blah blah...". We need more details to help him imho. :-)

Comment: You may be looking at the wrong question. None of that is in this one and the symptoms are actually quite specific.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem - Windows 8.1 with i7 4700MQ- quad core -> one core - specifically always core 2 gets hot.

I found a workaround for the problem - after waking up from sleep - go to each windows explorer window that is open and press Ctrl+N -> this  opens the same folder in a new window.

Do this for all your Windows Explorer windows that were open when you computer went to sleep.

After you have opened the new windows for all -> close the old windows -> Voila! your explorer CPU usage drops to negligible and CPU temp also comes down - don't know why it happens though!

Hope that helps!

Comment: That will work, but it's still ugly to do. I have the same problem. After resume it's the total commander and explorer exe  that take 100% of one thread each!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think much diagnostics is needed: Its a driver that does not support a certain sleep state.

Besides sleep, does this also happen when you hibernate?
How about in safe mode?

I dont think its a process per say, I just think it is a driver that is having trouble, literally, waking up.

Update from HP and if fails, then (try) to go to the original vendor.